# Forcing *print-circle* when loading a file into SBCL

Tags: common-lisp, slime, circular-list

I'm using a lot of circular lists in my code, and would like `*print-circle*` to be automatically set to `t` upon file load. I added the line `(setf *print-circle* t)` to my file, and thought that would help.

However, when I load the file into SLIME using C-c C-k, this doesn't seem to work - if I attempt to use the loaded code to print a circular list, the REPL gets thrown into an infinite loop *unless* I *manually* type `(setf *print-circle* t)` into the REPL after loading. I'm not sure precisely why this is happening - I only started getting this behaviour after I started using proper packaging and SLIME.

For the record, my package declarations (and anything else I thought might be relevant) are as follows:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload "priority-queue")
  (load "utilities.fasl")) ;;to avoid compilation issues

(defpackage :tournament
  (:use :cl :priority-queue :utilities))

(in-package :tournament)

(setf *print-circle* t) ;should work, but doesn't
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does this have to do with Emacs (tag `emacs`)? Emacs had variable `print-circle`, not `*print-circle*`, and the code that defines and uses such things is separate from SBCL etc.

Comment: @Drew SLIME is an Emacs package for running an external Lisp invocation in an Emacs buffer.

Comment: @Drew: You make a valid point, especially since I have the SLIME tag. I've removed the tag accordingly.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, but `*print-circle*` is not an Emacs variable and has no effect on Emacs printing. Its effect on SBCL presumably is unaffected by and does not affect Emacs.

Comment: @MrSinister13: Thanks; I think that will reduce confusion.

Comment: @Drew But his problem only occurs when using SLIME, which is Emacs-specific.

Comment: @Barmar: Where does it say that? Maybe SLIME is the only way he is interacting with SBCL. To me, this is an SBCL question, and I doubt that Emacs is relevant.  It doesn't bother me if MrSinister13 adds the tag back, but I doubt that anyone looking to help with Emacs questions will be able to help with this. Or if they can, I expect it will have to do with their knowledge of SBCL, not their knowledge of Emacs.

Comment: @Drew He said "I only started getting this error after I started using proper packaging and SLIME"

Comment: @Barmar: OK, maybe you're right then. Hopefully he will get some help with the problem, and not just comments about whether Emacs is relevant. ;-)

Comment: What versions are you using?  With SLIME 2014-03-27 and SBCL 1.1.12 and this file: `(defpackage :tournament (:use :cl)) (in-package :tournament) (setf *print-circle* t)`, `*print-circle*` evaluates to `t` in the REPL after a `C-c C-k` and circular lists print fine.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: I'm using SBCL 1.1.18.27-500983b and SLIME 20140429.744.

Comment: I upgraded by sbcl to match.  I can't find that exact slime version, but I tried the 2.5 and 2.6 releases.  I still can't reproduce.  The only other thing I can think of is to do `(setq slime-contribs '(slime-fancy))` in emacs before loading slime, if you aren't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to wrap the setting of `*print-circle*` in an `eval-when`:

```
(eval-when (:load-toplevel :execute)
  (setq *print-circle* t))
```